# The Dataflow data load is not showing up in BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I am loading pubsub json messages in to a  BigQuery table using Dataflow. I am flattening the Json messages using pandas dataframe and creating a smaller dataframe from it selecting few columns from it. I am converting this small dataframe to a json string using to_json() function on dataframe. This json is being returned to beam for loading into bigquery table using beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery().
The job is created fine and runs without showing any error but I do not see any data in the bigquery table
I am totally perplexed..What is happening here?
My Dataflow code:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        messages = (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=input_subscription
            ).with_output_types(bytes)
            | "UTF-8 bytes to string" >> beam.Map(lambda msg: msg.decode("utf-8"))
            | "Parse JSON messages" >> beam.Map(parse_json_message)
            | "Fixed-size-windows" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
            )

        # Output the results into BigQuery table.
    result = ( messages | "Write to Big Query" >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
            table = output_table,
            schema=table_schema,
            write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND'
        ))

    _= (result.failed_rows_with_errors | "Get Errors" >>beam.Map( lambda e: {
        "destination" : e[0],
        "row" : json.dumps(e[1]),
        "error_message": e[2][0]["message"]
        })
        | "Write Errors" >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
                table = "da-dwh-dev:test_dataset_for_all.error_log"
schema=error_schema,
                write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND
            )

My json processing code:
row = json.loads(message)
    df = pd.json_normalize(row, max_level = 4)
    df.columns = [ x.strip().replace('-','_').replace('.','_').upper() for x in df.columns]
    df.fillna('').astype(str)
    select_df =  df[["KEY_DATA", "VALUE_DATA_KV_QUOTE_LASTPRICEDDATE", "VALUE_DATA_KV_QUOTE_REPRICEONOPEN", "VALUE_DATA_KV_QUOTE_LOCKED"]]
    return select_df.to_json(orient = "records")
```

I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Could you go through the worker logs of the pipeline to find errors?<br>

Comment: I see following error in log : google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/da-dwh-dev/datasets/test_dataset_for_all/tables/TEST_INSERT_TO_BQ/insertAll?prettyPrint=false: Invalid value at 'rows[0].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), "{ "name" : "john Doe", "address" : " XYZ street" , "City" : "Gotham"}". It is a very simple json mesage.  I am using  beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery. I am not able to figure out why is it using rows[0].json

Comment: From the error message, it seems like the issue is with JSON format.Is it possible to try this "{name:'john Doe', address:'XYZ street' , City : 'Gotham'}" or \[{name:'john Doe', address:'XYZ street' , City : 'Gotham'},\] format?<br>

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are having the [same problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444309/cannot-insert-data-into-bigquery-from-dataflow-using-python-sdk).

Like you, I presumed that BigQuery was expecting a JSON object, or some other sort of string, or maybe even binary object.  But it just needed a dictionary.

You can look at the question that I linked above, but I think maybe all you have to do is remove the `json.dumps`.