# Cannot insert data into BigQuery from Dataflow (using Python SDK)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to figure out the proper schema that BigQuery is expecting when I am trying to write from Dataflow into BigQuery.

I took the Apache Beam [streaming pubsub-to-pubsub example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/streaming_wordcount.py) and merely changed the last step, which originally streamed back to a pubsub topic, and instead tried to write to a BigQuery table.

#### Original (relevant portion)

```py
    output = (
        counts
        | 'format' >> beam.Map(format_result)
        | 'encode' >>
        beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8')).with_output_types(bytes))

    # Write to PubSub.
    # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
    output | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic)
```

which I switched to

```py
    output = (
        counts
        | 'format' >> beam.Map(format_result)

        output | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            known_args.output_table,
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
            schema='"data":"STRING"',
        )
```

#### The error

I then send some messages to the pubsub topic that is being read.  Those messages are properly processed (in a streaming fashion), such that the count of similar words is calculated, and there is an attempt to push that count to BigQuery.  Then I receive the following error in the logs from Dataflow:

> message: "There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'message': 'POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/MY-PROJECT/datasets/MY-DATASET/tables/MY-TABLE/insertAll?prettyPrint=false: Invalid value at 'rows[0].json' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct), "another: 5"', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}]}]"

I just manually sent 5 messages that said `"And here's another message."`, hence why `"another: 5"` is one of the messages that it is attempting to send.

#### Other details

- The table does exist.  It has only one column, that is simply called "data" and is of type STRING.
- I have also tried a more full schema that also contained the table information, like this: `'{"fields":[{"name": "data", "type": "STRING"}]}'`, and a few other variations.
- I have tried to alter the format of what is being sent to BigQuery, with the following variations:

```py
        output = (
            counts
            | "format" >> beam.Map(format_result)
            | "encode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode("utf-8")).with_output_types(bytes)
        )

        output | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            known_args.output_topic,
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
            schema='"data":"STRING"',
        )
```

and

```py
        output = (
            counts
            | "format" >> beam.Map(format_result)
            | "encode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode("utf-8"))
        )

        output | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            known_args.output_topic,
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
            schema='"data":"STRING"',
        )
```

I understand that I am somehow sending in the wrong format, but (a) the error message is insufficiently helpful for me to completely solve the problem, and (b) I cannot find *any* examples on line of Dataflow pushing to BigQuery using the Python SDK and windowed streaming.

The two elements of the error that most confuse me:

1. `'rows[0].json'` makes it seem to me that it is attempting (successfully??) to call the `json` method on the row, which probably only makes sense if this is somehow happening in Javascript.
2. It mentions `type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct`, and I am not creating a protobuf in Dataflow, nor is the BigQuery schema in a protobuf.  (BigQuery has its own format, which is mostly compatible with protobufs, but distinct.)

Comment: Can you provide an example json you are trying to write to BigQuery?

Comment: I didn't provide the example JSON because I had provided both (a) the link to the exact Apache Beam example code I was using, and (b) the pub-sub message that I had sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution to my (OP) problem

I was *sending data* in the wrong format, and it was unclear to me the format that I was supposed to send the data in.

Again, my **BigQuery table schema** was:

```bash
> bq show --schema --format prettyjson --project_id <MY_PROJECT> <MY_DATASET>.<MY_TABLE>
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "data",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

In order to be able to *write* into that schema, I needed (in Python) to ***send* the following *Python dictionary object***:

```py
{
  "data": "<MY_DATA>"
}
```

It was not obvious (nor could I find any documentation) stating that I needed to be sending an object to BigQuery that was *just* a dictionary (I kept sending it as a JSON string), nor that I needed to explicitly state the field-name:data as a key:value object.

#### Solution to OP (only relevant parts)

I altered the streaming wordcount example referenced in the OP as follows (only capturing elements that were different from the original code):

```py
        def format_result(word_count):
            (word, count) = word_count
            return {"data": f"{word}:{count}"} # This formatting is altered

        output = (
            counts
            | "format" >> beam.Map(format_result) # No further encoding is needed
        )

        output | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            known_args.output_table,
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
            schema={"fields": [{"name": "data", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]}, # This is what I eventually used, but I think my original format string was also fine. There are multiple ways to express the schema.
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things you can change to ensure **WriteToBigQuery** is working fine:

- Try to pass the schema as a dictionary without casting it to a string.

  ```
  table_schema = {
      "fields": [
         {"name": "col_1", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
         {"name": "col_2", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
         {"name": "col_3", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
      ]
  }
  ```
- Fill in the required options properly to reduce the debugging scope:

  ```
  beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
      project="project_id",
      dataset="dataset_name",
      table="table_name",
      schema=table_schema,
      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,          
      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
      method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
    )
  ```
- You can't just push all the data from the PubSub to the BigQuery table without cleaning and having the appropriate schema.
- You can't use schema=SCHEMA_AUTODETECT with streaming based on the documentation:

> Schema auto-detection is not supported for streaming inserts into
> BigQuery. Only for File Loads

Answer (score 1):

Please check this example about how to define the table schema:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Python/bigquery/write_bigquery.py

BTW: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook contains a lot of useful and simple examples.